# KairosDB - aggregate, groupby, than aggregate again

Tags: kairosdb

KairosDB version 1.1.3-1.

I have dataPoints with `[time, name, key, value]`. 
Is it possible to at first group them by `name` and `key`, then aggregate results, then group them again by `key` and then aggregate again?

So basically:

1. All values for `name1`+`key1` and all values for `name2`+`key1`
2. Aggregate each by average (period 10 sec)
3. Group aggregated results by `key1` (I want to combine results here)
4. Aggregate given results by sum (same period, 10 sec).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cannot do that. You only can group once, and cannot merge the groups afterwards.

We did our own extension to kairosdb supporting a similar feature (merging all groups of a metric with a sum/avg...), but it's so intrusive (we override kairosdb query handler by our own) that we did not contribute to open source.

Edit: You may try to use kairosDB post-processing script that is designed for that: https://github.com/kairosdb/kairos-script